# Shell Command to open Internet Explorer only site generates errors: Invalid argument or file not found

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I'm trying to open Internet Explorer for a specific IE only site.

Depending on the amount of quotes I get

> invalid argument

or

> file not found

Disclaimer:
Ignore any out of place spaces and capital letters. I can't copy paste my code since my PC has no internet connection and is inside a virtual machine at work. I'm typing this on my phone.

On cmd

```
%program files%\internet explorer/iexplore.exe -private myurl
```

works fine

On Excel, Shell commands throws a error  file not found

```
URL = "%program files%\internet explorer/iexplore.exe -private myurl" 
Shell """" & URL & """"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay so I found the correct way to open internet explorer in vba here it is

> Sub openie ()
>
> Dim iebrowser as object
>
> set iebrowser = createobject("InternetExplorer.Application")
>
> iebrowser.visible =true iebrowser.Navigate2 "www.google.pt"
>
> End sub

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Shell Environ("ProgramFiles") & _
      "\internet explorer\iexplore.exe -private http://www.google.com"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701967/get-path-of-program-files-folder-that-contains-32-bit-programs

Comment: The path is correct I copy pasted the ie location to vba however I still tried this same error file not found

Comment: With the space in "program files"? In any case - seems like you cannot use that via Shell