# How to get the 64 bit "Program Files" folder path from a 32 bit program

Tags: c, winapi

I need to get the 64 bit "Program Files" folder path (the one that defaults to *C:\Program Files*, not the one that default to *C:\Program Files (x86)*) from a 32 bit program and for this I planned to use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath).

Unfortunately it seems impossible to get that path from a 32 bit program running on a 64 bit Windows, at least this is what I conclude from the [remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid#remarks) of the documentation.

Is there another method to do this?

I'm seriously thinking of stripping the `" (x86)"` from the path I'm getting with `SHGetKnownFolderPath`, or use some other ugly hack.

Comment: mybe this will help
http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/W.Langdon/getenv/
search for "ProgramFiles"

Comment: *GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"ProgramW6432", ...)*

Comment: And why a 32-bit program will need path to 64-bit software? What it will do there?

Comment: Because it's an installation program that should run on both 32 bit and 64 bit Windows.

Comment: Did you try using `FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64`? In the remarks section you linked, one mention of it says "not supported under 32-bit **operating systems**" and the other says "not supported for 32-bit **applications**". It wouldn't surprise me if the second comment was a mistake. Otherwise there really wouldn't be much point in having that folder ID in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the registry is an option.

Provided that you've properly determined that the host OS is 64-bit, you can read `ProgramFilesDir` from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`.

There should be no problem reading that key, but one nitpick is that the key is accurate only if it hasn't been changed since the last system startup. I doubt it's frequently changed on any reasonable system, though.

---

As suggested by @RbMM in comments, reading `ProgramW6432` from the environment is another reliable option.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11211727/5958455), this environment variable is:

```
Host OS  Program  %ProgramW6432%
-------  -------  --------------
32-bit   32-bit   (not present)
64-bit   32-bit   C:\Program Files
64-bit   64-bit   C:\Program Files
```

Comment: Note that by default, a 32-bit application will transparentely read `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`. There the program path is again `C:\Program Files (x86)` (Note the `WOW6432Node`!). AFAIK it depends how you open the registry key

Comment: Well, that's what I wanted to avoid, but apparently there are not many other options.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I got an update with the answer. Check it out.

Comment: @Jabberwocky see [32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/32-bit-and-64-bit-application-data-in-the-registry) and [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view). To access the 64-bit version of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion` from a 32-bit app, open the key using the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag.